# C++ Debug Error R6010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

```
#include"../../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main(){
    int x=-1;
    if(x==-1) error("ERROR!");
}
```

Above is my little program to use the `error` function specially defined by Bjarne Stroustrup in his book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++".

I was able to use his special `error` function before. But after some exercise, this error comes out:

```
Debug Error! R6010 -abort has been called...
```

I might have modified something but I don't know what. Ever since that unknown change, I can no longer use the `error` function. It is convenient for my exercises because it replaces the `try` and `catch` construction.

You can find the header file `std_lib_facilities.h` [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h).

I am using Visual Studio 2012. My computer has Visual Studio 2015 installed. I have tried to use Visual Studio 2015 to compile this program but it became worse, I messed up somewhere, and I wanted to know where, but I was incapable to do so.

Thanks in advance to anyone who is willing to help.

P/S: I reinstalled VS 2012, but `error` still fails to work.

Comment: Don't you miss a hash sign in front of the `include`?

Comment: there is a hash sign in the original cpp source file. I accidentally left it out here. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(x=-1)` be `if(x == -1)`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for pointing out the mistake, but it still fails to work.

Comment: what do yu expect to happen - you are throwing an exception and not catching it. I expect vs runtime to give you this error

Comment: @pm100 I found similar answers like yours on the web too. But the weird thing is the 'error' function "worked" before. But no longer does. If it didn't work from the beginning I might not have such a headache...

Comment: i suspect it wasnt working before - maybe you were not calling it. try putting in a try catch and see what you catch

Comment: After putting try catch everything works well. But I am wondering why I succeeded in using this error function without using try-catch in several programs before this happened. In the book the error function is used without try-catch, I supposed it might be a shortcut for the try-catch construction. I try to look into the header file for clues but I can understand nothing.